# how to create dynamic listview by using json local assets file

Tags: java, android, json, xml

**i want to create dynamic list view with 3 row and retrieve the data from local J SON 
thank in advance**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Exercise: Study the [help], learn [ask], and take the [tour]

Comment: Seems you are new to android development, if so then I would suggest you to start with attending courses available over Udacity or any such sites.

Answer (score 0):

Listview(or RecyclerView) is used to display data's which rows count changes over time. In your case you need only 3 filed then use 3 TextViews. If you should display more than one record then you can use ListView/RecyclerView.

If data changes you need to recreate the adapter and set it on ListView.
On RecyclerView you can use a building function called notifyDataSetChanged().

Hope it helps.